# Wix Toolset - Creating a second patch

Tags: wix

I have created a patch (.msp) in Wix toolset and this Updating my project as I would expect.

However I am having trouble creating a second patch on top of this, and have a few questions I was hoping someone could help with.

1) When generating the transformation do I do this from the original unpatched .msi or from the .msi containing the fixes that would have been included in patch 1.

2) In my Patch.wxs - what process do I need to follow? Things I have tried including incrementing the media id, increasing the version number of the patch family? Maybe I need a whole new patch family? Do I need a new cabinet file?

3) How do I add this new patch to my bootstrapper? Simply adding another  node causes multiple control panel entries.

I'm not sure what source code to provide, so if you need anymore let me know.

Patch.wxs:

```
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
<Patch AllowRemoval='no' Manufacturer='Test' DisplayName='Test' Description='Test' 
Classification='Update'>

    <Media Id='3' Cabinet='TestPatch.cab'>
        <PatchBaseline Id='TestPatch'>
            <Validate UpgradeCode='yes' ProductVersion='Update' ProductVersionOperator='LesserOrEqual' ProductId='yes' />
        </PatchBaseline>
    </Media>

    <PatchFamilyRef Id='TestPatchFamily' />

    <PatchFamily Id='TestPatchFamily' Version='2.0.0.0' Supersede='yes'>
        <PropertyRef Id='ProductVersion' />
        <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
    </PatchFamily>

</Patch>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bundle.wxs in the Bootstrapper was fine, I had to add the

```
MinorUpdateTargetRTM="yes"
```

attribute to the Patch element.

Thank you to this [post](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Creating-multiple-Minor-Updates-td7586073.html).